# Expectation of exponential of brownian motion is martingale.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $B_t$ be a brownian motion.  Find $a$ and $b$ so that $W_t=exp(aB_t+bt)$ is martingale relative to the filtration $F_t^B$.

My attempt:  For $s \leq t$ we have $E(W_t | F_s)=E(e^{b(t-s)}e^{a(B_t-B_s)}W_s | F_s)$.  We know that $B_t-B_s$ is independent from $B_s$ and that $B_t-B_s$ has zero mean.  It seems like we are almost there but I can't put the rest of the pieces together.

Comment: Can you compute $E[\exp(bX)]$ if $b\in\Bbb R$ and $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: It's inside the conditional expectation and we can't say that $B_t-B_s$ is independent from $F_s$ so I can't really see how that helps.  To answer your question thought we can expand the taylor serires for $e^t$ then take the integral with respect to $dP$

Comment: One way is to use the Ito formula and then set the drift equal to zero.

Comment: @ian unfortunately I don't have access to the big rigs.  I have to prove it more or less straight from the definitions.

Comment: In fact, $B_t-B_s$ *is* independent of $F_s$, so $E[e^{a(B_t-B_s)}\mid F_s] = E[e^{a(B_t-B_s)}]$, by independence.

Comment: @JohnDawkins is it a general fact that if f is independent from $G$ then E(fg | G)=E(f)E(g|G)$?  thanks.

Comment: In general, if $f$ is independent of $G$ then $E[f\mid G] = E[f]$. If also $g$ is $G$-measurable then $E[fg\mid G] = E[f]\cdot g$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins that makes a lot more sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know is $Ee^{c(B_v-B_u)}=e^{c^{2} (v-u)/2} $ for $u<v$.

In a martingale expectations remain  a constant. So we need $Ee^{aB_t+bt}=1$ for all $t$ (since $B_0=0$). This gives $e^{a^{2}t/2}e^{bt}=1$ or $b=-a^{2}/2$.

To show that $e^{aB_t-\frac  {a^{2}} 2 t}$ is  martinagle do the following:

$E(e^{aB_t-\frac  {a^{2}} 2 t}|\mathcal F_s)=E(e^{a(B_t-B_s)|\mathcal F_s) E(e^{aB_s-\frac  {a^{2}} 2 t}}|\mathcal F_s)$. Of course, $E(e^{aB_s-\frac  {a^{2}} 2 t}|\mathcal F_s)=e^{aB_s-\frac  {a^{2}} 2 t}$. Also, $E(e^{a(B_t-B_s)}|\mathcal F_s)=E(e^{a(B_t-B_s)})=e^{a^{2}(t-s)/2} $. I will let you finish from here.